# Cairosvg with pyinstaller "No such file or directory:"

Tags: python, pyinstaller, cairo, pycairo

I'm using python 3.7 and I want to create an executable from a script that use "cairosvg" package, the exe gives me this error while trying to run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testCairo.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "cairosvg\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "pathlib.py", line 1199, in read_text
  File "pathlib.py", line 1186, in open
  File "pathlib.py", line 1039, in _opener
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\moham\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI135122\\cairosvg\\VERSION'
[16072] Failed to execute script testCairo
```

any one has an idea how to solve this error ?

my code is only import cairosvg as the following:

```
import cairosvg 

print('test')
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to include the cairosvg folder in the pyinstaller command?

`Pyinstaller --add-binary <path to cairosvg>;cairosvg testCairo.py`

The package should be in your python installation folder, something like: "C:\Users<User>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\cairosvg".

The command should copy the cairosvg package folder from its location into your exe's dist folder. If you prefer one single file, you could also add "--onefile" to the pyinstaller command.